# LINQ to NHibernate, how to do this query

Tags: c#, nhibernate, .net-4.0

I have two entities, EntityA and EntityB. EntityB in the database has a FK reference to EntityA.Id, so for every one row in EntityA there are potentially zero, one or many rows in EntityB. Commonly this is referred to simply as a one-to-many relationship.

I have my two entities mapped with NHibernate 3.2 like this:

```
<class name="EntityA" table="EntityA">
    <id name="Id" type="Guid" column="id">
       <generator class="guid.comb" />
    </id>
    <set name="EntityBs" lazy="false" inverse="true" cascade="all" table="EntityB">
        <key column="id" />
        <one-to-many class="EntityB" />
    </set>
    <properties...
</class>
<class name="EntityB" table="EntityB">
    <id name="Id" type="Guid" column="id">
       <generator class="guid.comb" />
    </id>
    <many-to-one name="EntityA" class="EntityA" column="entityAId" />
    <properties...
</class>
```

I cannot figure out how to write this LINQ query. I want all the rows of EntityA that do not have any rows in EntityB with a foreign key reference to EntityA.

Based on other examples I've found I've tried something like this:

```
var results = 
                nhSession.Query<EntityA>()
                .Where(x => !x.EntityBs.Any()).ToList();
```

What I want LINQ-to-NHibernate to emit is something like:

```
SELECT 
   id, 
   column1, 
   column2,
   etc..
FROM EntityA 
WHERE id NOT IN (
   SELECT entityAId
   FROM EntityB
)
```

Any help anyone can provide is greatly appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It is easier if you establish a bidirectional relationship between EntityA and EntityB. (Sorry, NHForge is down at the moment, otherwise I would link you to some docs).

Then you can write the query like this:

```
Session.Query<EntityA>
    .Where(x => !x.EntityBs.Any())
    .ToList();
```

Doing this without the bidirectional mapping is hard in Linq - I would use CreateCriteria or HQL instead.

Comment: I added the bidirectional relationship. I will edit my above original question to reflect this idea. However, the query does not work. It's selecting nothing even when it should.

Comment: OK, I got past another snag with the ISet being of the wrong type and now I see the query it's generating and it's just totally wrong and I have no clue what LINQ syntax would yield the proper query. I think I will have to abandon this direction. Thanks for your response though.

Comment: Can you post the exact SQL query that you are looking for?